# Separar secuencias cuando un valor se repite - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Deseamos realizar un programa que reciba una sucesión de números enteros, el primero de los cuales indicará la cantidad de números que se van a leer, y realice la ordenación de las secuencias.

Cuando encontremos una secuencia ordenaremos, de menor a mayor, todos los elementos pertenecientes a dicha secuencia. Una vez ordenadas todas las secuencias se mostrarán por pantalla todos los números ordenados en sus secuencias.

```
 Entradas
 9 5 4 3 6 3 7 1 7 5
 Salidas
 3 4 5 6 1 3 7 5 7
```

Esto es lo que llevo al momento pero lo que intento hacer no funciona

```
   let cad = [];//SECUENCIAS
   let numero = Number(prompt("Numero"));
   let cad1 = new Array(numero);
   for (let i=0;i<numero;i++){
   cad[i] = Number(prompt(`Numero ${i+1}`));}

   for (let i=0;i<numero;i++) {
   for (let j=0;j<numero;j++){
   while (cad1[i].indexOf(cad[j])<1){
   cad1.push(cad[j]);}
   }}
```

Quiero que al momento de de encontrar un repetido corte ahí, lo ordene y continué con el mismo ciclo donde se quedo y almacenar las secuencias juntas para imprimirlas.

¡¡EDIT!!: Necesito que si ya está 5,4,3,6 (el siguiente es un 3, por lo cuál no se agrega porque está repetido) entonces ordeno y queda 3,4,5,6 y comienzo de nuevo a partir del 3 y queda 3,7,1 (porque sigue 7 y no entra por estar repetido) y ahora ordeno 1,3,7 y ya para finalizar ordeno el 5,7-- El "9" solo representa cuantos números van a ingresar. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera simple de llevar la cuenta y revisar si tienes un número repetido es utilizando un objeto como diccionario (`{ }`).

```js
var numeros = [5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 7, 1, 7, 5];

var secuencia = {};
var grupos = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
  var n = numeros[i];
  
  if (secuencia[n]) {
    grupos.push(secuencia);
    secuencia = {};
  }
  
  secuencia[n] = true;  
}
grupos.push(secuencia);

console.log(grupos);
```

Hasta aquí tienes los grupos separados dentro de un array, ahora lo que tienes que hacer es iterarlo, extraer los nombres de las propiedades y ordenarlo.

Answer (score 0):

no estoy seguro de que es lo que quieres hacer con los loops pero una forma de organizar los números de menor a mayor seria:

```
      var points = [9, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 7, 1, 7, 5];
      points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

espero te sirva de algo  ;)

Comment: Gracias, eso busco, solo que necesito que si ya está 5,4,3,6 (el siguiente es un 3, por lo cuál no se agrega porque está repetido) entonces ordeno y queda 3,4,5,6 y comienzo de nuevo a partir del 3 y queda 3,7,1 (porque sigue 7 y no entra por estar repetido) y ahora ordeno 1,3,7 y ya para finalizar ordeno el 5,7-- El "9" solo representa cuantos números van a ingresar. Espero me ayudes